# How can I send a php object through ajax using json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following ajax code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/conversation/test',
                data: { conversation: JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($conversation) ?>) },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

Now I have on my test.php:

```
<?php

    $conversation = json_decode($_POST['conversation']);


 ?>

<?php foreach ($conversation->getUsers() as $conUser) {
    // Skip current user
    if ($conUser->getId() == UserSession::getUserId()) {
       continue;
    } ?>
    <a href="/<?php echo $conUser->getUri(); ?>/"><?php echo $conUser->getName(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

And my response on the console is:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method stdClass::getUsers() in     <b>/Users/msalamanca/PhpStorm/pinporn/trunk/application/views/default/conversation/test.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `$conversation` is just decoded JSON you passed to ajax? `json_decode` is just for converting JSON string to array - please review http://us3.php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php. If you want to use getter `getUsers()` you need to implement some class with properties and getters/setters. You cannot use getter on array.

Comment: @Cockootec Technically, `json_decode` returns an object by default, and only returns an array if you explicitly tell it to by using the second parameter. That being said, the sentiment of your post is correct. There is no way for PHP to know that the JSON should be converted into some class that has a specific method.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I can get the object back?

Comment: What is the value of `$conversation` here `echo json_encode($conversation)`? And what exactly is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am doing a chat, and I want to keep separated the messages. so that I can call this function that will display all messages. $conversation has all those messages. where I am doing the ajax I have this object. So I want to send the object to test.php and from there handle the whole display and presentation of the messages.

Comment: I kind understand now, before sending the object, I have an Object(COnversationModel) and after I get just an Object(StdClass)

Comment: json is for data. it's not a general serialization system. you cannot pass actual objects around, and json strings will decode only to a stdClass object (or array) in PHP

Comment: But what do you mean by "$conversation has all those messages"? You should include the output of `var_dump($conversation);` (where `$conversation` is the value before you encode it) in your question.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks , I think I understand. Now i need to find out how to send al this using ajax and then unserialize it again so that I can use the way I want

Comment: @monica: it'll just be a normal php data structure. `var_dump($conUser)` will show you the structure, and you can do whatever for loops necessary to extract the data you need.

Comment: bt it doesn't, I keep getting that error. cause on one side I have the object of type ConversationModel, and when I decode I have the object of type StdClass. So of course I can't do anything. I need to figure out how to pass the object without losing its properties

Comment: Don't double-encode.  There is no reason for the `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I understood what I was doing wrong. So on my view, I did the following:

```
    <div id="messages-widget">

    </div>

    <!--  Updates the conversation display and check for new messages  -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.post( "/conversation/messages", { conId: <?php echo $conversation->getId(); ?> })
                 .done(function (data) {
                      $('#messages-widget').html(data);
            });


        });

    </script>
```

Then in my Controller I just did the following:

```
    public function messages($args=array()) {

        $conId = $args['conId'];

        // Get current conversation
        $conversation = ConversationModel::getConversationById($conId);

        DataHolder::getInstance()->addObject('conversation', $conversation);
    }
```

So like this, my view will have the conversation object that I wanted, with its properties. Doing it like this, I can use the getters and setters that I needed.

Comment: That looks better! One thing you might need to take care of is to check wether the actual user is allowed to view the conversion requested.

Comment: Yeah I just removed a bunch of code from the answer, just to show the idea :)